# How to use out-of-datagrid scope variable inside an ItemRenderer?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, itemrenderer

I'm binding an array of items to a data grid using `ItemRenderer`. I use the `data` variable to control the bindable data. I also have `someComponentVariable` that need be inserted into every row but its declared at the component scope, so the data grid doesn't seem to reconize it (compile error).

How can I use this variable (`someComponentVariable`) inside the `ItemRenderer`?

#### Code Example

```
<mx:DataGrid id="userBonusesGrid" width="100" height="248" showHeaders="false" wordWrap="true">
    <mx:columns>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="" width="36">
            <mx:itemRenderer>
                <mx:Component>
                    <mx:VBox verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">
                        <ns1:SidePanelBonus 
                            bonusName="{data.name}" description="{data.description}" 
                            arrow="{someComponentVariable}">
                        </ns1:SidePanelBonus>   
                    </mx:VBox>
                </mx:Component>
            </mx:itemRenderer>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
    </mx:columns>
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `someComponentVariable` is a public property of the class enclosing `DataGrid`, you can use `outerDocument` to access it from a `component`.

```
<ns1:SidePanelBonus bonusName="{data.name}" description="{data.description}" 
    arrow="{outerDocument.someComponentVariable}">
</ns1:SidePanelBonus>
```

See the "using the Component tag" section in [Creating inline item renderers and editors](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_6.html#192573) for more info about `outerDocument`

Comment: make sure to cast the outerDocument variable

Answer (score 0):

No you can not use it at all. Each itemRenderer in data grid can only access the item for which the renderer was created. And this is done purposely because itemRendrers change dynamically, they are not bound for data forever, when you scroll, the items get scrolled not the renderers, they remain in same position or they might change, but corresponding item renderer's data always changes when you scroll. They dont share one to one relationship.

The only solution is to pass the data in the item in the form of some parent child relationship.