# Error 1120: Access of undefined property

Tags: apache-flex, subclass

I have a `<mx:Script>` on the main file, where I define this:

```
[Bindable]
private var dpCols:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
{'prx':'bl', 'nmb':'Blanco', 'ral':'RAL1013', 'hex':'E8E4CD'},
{'prx':'am', 'nmb':'Amarillo', 'ral':'RAL1005', 'hex':'C79E03'},
{'prx':'gr', 'nmb':'Gris Perla', 'ral':'RAL7045', 'hex':'8E939E'}
 ]);
```

I can use it as a dataProvider in many places, but not here:

```
<mx:TileList dataProvider="{dpCols}">
    <mx:itemRenderer>
    <mx:Component>
        <mx:Box backgroundColor="{int('0x' + data.hex)}"
            height="64" width="72">
            <mx:Label text="{data.ral}" textAlign="center" width="100%"/>
            <mx:Label text="{data.nmb}" textAlign="center" width="100%"/>
        </mx:Box>
    </mx:Component>
    </mx:itemRenderer>
</mx:TileList>
```

This TileList is within a `<radg:RaDG>` (my subclass for AdvancedDataGrid), `<radg:columns>`, `<mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn>`, `<mx:itemEditor>` and `<mx:Component>`. If I put it outside, it just works. But I need it to put it has the itemEditor.

How should I refer to `dpCols` then? (or how can I solve this error?)

Thanks!

Comment: Also, you need to make the method or property `public` not `private`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [`outerDocument`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mxml/component.html), since you're inside the `<mx:Component>` tag.  See the "Using the Component Tag" section in [this Adobe docs page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=cellrenderer_6.html) or this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1453943/how-to-use-out-of-datagrid-scope-variable-inside-an-itemrenderer).

If you're getting particularly tricky with nesting, you may need to use [`parentDocument`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/core/UIComponent.html#parentDocument) instead, but it sounds like `outerDocument` should work in your case (only one nesting of `<mx:Component>` tags).

Usage:

```
<mx:TileList dataProvider="{outerDocument.dpCols}" />
```

Comment: Thx! It works only with parentDocument, though I only can see only one nesting with <mx:Component>, as you said... well, whatever! :D

Comment: If you move your inline component or ItemRenderer into it's own file then you need to change `outerDocument` to `owner.parentDocument` or `owner.document` since `outerDocument` is a property provided only to the inline `fx:Component` tag. 

This information is in the link to the Adobe docs in the answer above.